# Webkit/Blink: child padding set in %, when the parent has padding as well

Tags: css, webkit, blink

I am seing a strange behavior in all Webkit|Blink-based browsers I can reach (Opera 16+, Chrome 12, 29, Safari 5.1 Windows).

Assume we have a parent div, and a child block element inside it. If we set the child's `width:xx%` and some `padding:xx%`, the properties are calculated to the required values.

But if the parent has padding itself, the child's padding (which is in percents) does not respect the parent's paddings. I see this only in Webkit|Blink. The child's width does respect the parent's padding in all browsers. `box-sizing` seems not to influence this behavior.

For the example please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8YN/3/). The bottom's child is square, as it should be. And the top's child is not: its `padding-bottom:50%` and `width:50%` are calculated to different values. Again, in FF, IE (9 at least), pre-Blink Opera both dash-bordered blocks are square. And below are the code exerpts.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent padded"></div>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
.parent.padded{
    padding:20px 30px;
}
.parent:after{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;

    content:"";
}
```

Could anyone please help me make it clear: is it the engine's bug? Or maybe there is some explaination to this anywhere in the Spec?

Thanks!